# Compress dataprovider output when tests pass phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a testcase for phpunit 10 that uses a dataprovider:

```php
#[DataProviderExternal(\Tests\DataProvider::class, 'invalidEmailAddresses')]
public function test_validates_email_address(string $email): void
{
    // ... test
}
```

When I run the test, I get the output per item provided by the dataprovider.

```
✓ validates email address with data set ...                                                                                                                                                                   
✓ validates email address with data set ...                                                                                                                                                                        
✓ validates email address with data set ...                                                                                                                                                                          
✓ validates email address with data set ...
```

When all tests pass, I do not really care about this output. On some occasions there is ten or more lines which pollutes the test output and makes it hard to read. Ideally I would just like the test name when it passes:

```
✓ validates email address
```

I could loop over the array of values that the dataprovider providers and then assert:

```php
foreach($data as $email)
{
    $this->assert(...);
}
```

This would work but it would defeat the purpose of using a data provider and not give me an indication of the data set that failed when the test fails.

Is there a way to compress this output when the test succeeds and show it in its entirety when any datasets fail?

Comment: Have you tested `--display notifications`? https://docs.phpunit.de/en/10.3/textui.html#details-about-issues